# Creating SQL trigger that only affects specific row

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have two tables created inventory and customer_sales. Individuals working in the warehouse can't have access to the customer_sales table.

So I added an additional field to inventory table called num_sales.

I want to create a trigger functions that whenever a new customer sale is added. It will correspond to the specific inventory_item that was sold's row and not the entire table.

This is what I have so far.

```
ALTER TABLE inventory 
ADD num_sales INT 

UPDATE movies SET num_sales = 0;

ALTER TABLE movies ALTER COLUMN num_rentals INT NOT NULL;

GO
CREATE TRIGGER tr_movies_num_rentals_add
   ON customer_sales FOR INSERT
   AS
   BEGIN
     UPDATE inventory
       SET num_sales = num_sales + (SELECT sale_status_code FROM INSERTED)
       WHERE 1 = (SELECT sale_status_code FROM INSERTED);
   END;
```

Note: 
sale_status_code values: 1=sold, 2=reserved, 3=lost.

UPDATE: I am using Microsoft SQL server management studio. I am newbie and this is a question I have for school.

Comment: ***SQL*** is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... many things are vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** (and which version) you're using (please update tags accordingly)....

Comment: AND PLEASE DON'T SHOUT IN YOUR TITLE - no need to yell at everyone.....

Answer (score 0):

First assume inserted willhave multiple rows. SQL server triggers do not operate row by row. YOu need to join to inserted not use a subquery. Next if you want this to happen on insert, update and delete, then you need to use more than an INSert trigger. And the delete trigger should use a different formula than inserted and updated becasue you will be subtracting the value from the deleted table from the inventory total.